# update offer price

Tags: magento-1.9

I displayed offer price in individual page, if product have special price

```
<!-- If Product have Spl Price -->
        <?php 
        $regular_prc = round($_product->getPrice());
        $fnl_prc = round($_product->getFinalPrice());
         $curr_symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
        if($fnl_prc < $regular_prc):?>
            <span class="has_spl_prc_incart"><?php echo "OFFER PRICE " ."$curr_symbol " ."$fnl_prc" ; ?></span>


        <?php endif; ?>

         <!-- If Product have Spl Price -->
```

it's working fine but i added custom option to that product. Let us assume Drop down custom option

Test+100
Test1+200

if i select custom option offer value should not change how i fix it

Comment: after selecting offer value what you want to do?

Comment: if i change custom option that time offer price also changed based on custom option

Comment: custom option in product detail page right?You want to add or deduct the price and show that price right? or you just want to change the display amount only?

Comment: check this link http://dev.fitfurn.com/living/cane-single-chair-with-cushion.html. I need to update OFFER Price(Red Txt above cart) also while changing custom option

Answer (score 0):

You have the onchange function called `opConfig.reloadPrice()`

In that function change the text of has_spl_prc_incart class.Or add an id to that span and update the innerhtml value like this

```
<span class="has_spl_prc_incart" id="has_spl_prc_incart">OFFER PRICE ₹  15500</span>

document.getElementById("has_spl_prc_incart").innerHTML="new Value";
                        or
document.getElementById("has_spl_prc_incart").textContent="new Value";
```

Simply you can change like how the value change in the offerprice UP.

**Update**
You can search this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283691/where-is-the-path-of-opconfig-reloadprice-in-magento) to find where you want to edit or alter the jquery function.

Comment: In which file i have to use that onchange event

Comment: check the update